# About Running OSB foundation sample

Tags: osb

When I try to run OSB-100 foundation sample given on official oracle website hosted on `java.net`.

It is to be run on `Weblogic Server 10.3.x 11gR1 Patchset 2`.

I have installed latest versions of `OEPE+Weblogic Server` and `OSB`.

Still I get following error:

```
Target runtime `Oracle Weblogic Server 11gR1 Patchset2` not defined.
```

In the new *Server Wizard*, I am not able to find `WLS 11R1 Pacthset2`. I only get `Oracle Weblogic Server(10.3.6) 11gR1` which is `without a pacthset`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the OSB-100 foundation project go to Properties and there you have Targeted Runtimes and check Oracle Weblogic Server(10.3.6) 11gR1 instead of  Weblogic Server 10.3.x 11gR1 Patchset 2.
It worked for me.
Adrian